# Exceptions while I am extracting data from a Web site

Tags: java, exception, html-parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to extract data by zip codes from a Web site.The zip codes are read from a text file
and the results are written at the console. I have around 1500 zip codes. The program throws two kinds of exceptions:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-profile/...

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I thought the solution is to read only few data at the time. So, I used a counter, to count 200 zip codes from the text file and I stop the program for 5 minutes after I have data for 200 zip codes.
As I said, I still have the exceptions. So far, when I see the exception, I copy paste the available data, and I continue after that with the following zip codes.
But I want to read all data without interruptions.
Can be this possible? Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

This is my code for reading all data:

```
    while (br.ready())
        {
            count++;

            String s = br.readLine();
            String str="http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-profile/results.asp?Zip="+s; 
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(str).get();

            for (Element table : doc.select("table.DataTbl"))
            {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr")) 
                {
                    Elements tds = row.select("td");
                    if (tds.size() > 1)
                    {
                        if (tds.get(0).text().contains("Per capita income"))
                            System.out.println(s+","+tds.get(2).text());
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count%200==0)
            {
                Thread.sleep(300000);
                System.out.println("Stoped for 5 minutes");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(str).get();` to set the timeout as:

```
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(str);
        conn.timeout(300000); //5 minutes
        Document doc = conn.get();
```

Comment: @LaviniaTomole - Did you try the above as well? If yes, got the same error?

Comment: I am trying right now..so far it is working...but for 1500 zip codes it takes me a while...I will let you know....thank you!

Comment: I got the error "org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://www.moving.com/real-estate/city-profile/results.asp?Zip=629.." after 700 extractions.

Comment: Increase the timeout to 10 or 15 minutes and reduce your thread sleep, if you are still using that and then try. Should help.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea, if I do not use sleep()? I think the problem was fixed by setting the timeout, right? I mage the changes and I am waiting again :)

Comment: Yes. I don't think, sleep is doing anything other than interrupting your process.

Comment: It was interrupted again, but I could read more 200 data(900 in total). So the changes helped me a lot. I set timeout at 10 minutes only. Can I set as much I want? What should be the optimal time for timeout, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(str);
        conn.timeout(0); /Infinite Timeout

> Set the request timeouts (connect and read). If a timeout occurs, an
>   IOException will be thrown. The default timeout is 3 seconds (3000
>   millis). **A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout.**
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> millis - number of milliseconds before timing out connects or reads.
> ```
>
> **Returns:**
>
> ```
> this Connection, for chaining
> ```

[Source: jsoup API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)

Set timeout to zero. This way you won'y have to stop for 5 minutes.

Comment: I tried to modify the code:Connection.timeout(300000);(I want 5 minutes) and I have the error "The method timeout(int) is undefined for the type Connection"